# TD height not being applied in Firefox

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to figure out why my tables cells are not displaying at the height I specify:

```
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
<table style="border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 10px; padding: 0px;padding-top: 6px; margin: 0px;" align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="842" width="595">
<tbody>
<tr><td height="100">Test</td></tr>
<tr><td height="100">Test</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

On my browser (Firefox), this page displays with each cell taking 50% of the height of the table (covering the whole table) instead of the specified 100px each cell. I've tried every combination, setting the tr height (which actually doesn't exist), and the td height as I've posted.

I need to avoid using CSS as I'm generating HTML for emails and email clients are not very tolerant to CSS. I would like my table as much as possible to be set using HTML tag attributes.

**EDIT**

Now I'm really confused. Even setting the height with CSS doesn't work:

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 10px; padding: 0px;padding-top: 6px; margin: 0px;" align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="842" width="595">
<tbody>
<tr><td style="height: 100px;">Test</td></tr>
<tr><td style="height: 100px;">Test</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT**

Someone posted a JSFiddle in the comments saying it worked. But here is a screenshot of that fiddle on my browser (Firefox):
[image]

I guess the question now is why can I not set the row height on Firefox?

Comment: tr does not have height attribute..

Comment: Yeah I actually saw that while checking the properties. I tried it anyway, it's just ignored but for the life of my I can't figure out why the td height is not being applied.

Comment: its is working.... see demo ...http://jsfiddle.net/SjyqV/

Comment: Hey man, thank you for the time your putting into helping me. I've posted a screenshot of your fiddle on the question. I guess the question now is why is it not working on firefox?

Answer (score -2):

Just figured it out. On Firefox you must set `display: block;` in the CSS or the table height will not be applied:

```
<body>
<table style="border: 1px solid black; border-radius: 10px; padding: 0px;padding-top: 6px; margin: 0px; display: block;" align="left" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="842" width="595">
<tbody>
<tr><td height="100" style="display: block">Test</td></tr>
<tr><td height="100" style="display: block">Test</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: Indeed. I just tried adding display:block to a TD and TR and the HEIGHT property is getting applied.
BUT, it messes up the whole flow of the table - the TDs are flowing one BELOW the other (I guess like display:block elements should...)
So it seems like it's not a good idea to use display:block for TDs and TRs.

Comment: [This Mozilla bug from 1999](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=22274) contains a workaround: set `display:block;` on the `img` element. It’s marked as INVALID WONTFIX, saying it’s an interpretation issue of the spec… heh…